# Actual Performance Difference Between P1V3 and B3 in Azure App Service Plans

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

AT the time of this writing there are two comparable Linux plans

- Dev/Test, B3 - 7GB, 400ACU
- Prod - P1V3 - 8GB, 195 min ACU/vCPU (2 vCPU). This plan also offers auto-scale, staging slots, daily backups, more storage and traffic manager.

B3: $49/month
P1V3: $83

I currently have 22 apps on a B3 (Linux, .NET6). CPU is normally < 30%. Memory usage hovers at 90%. I think memory is one of those "you have it, I use it" situations. However, I cannot add more apps to it (it starts to fail).

From a performance point of view, is anyone aware of perceivable differences? P1V3 is almost twice the cost for what seems like 1GB of ram more (if you do not need the extra stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans):

> The new PremiumV3 pricing tier guarantees machines with faster processors (minimum 195 ACU per virtual CPU), SSD storage

So you'll very likely notice a performance increase if only due to the SSD, plus hopefully you can justify getting a 3 year reservation which will mean you only pay a couple of dollars more for premium v3 ([currently $53 for 3 years](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/linux/)).

Plus the great thing about [reservation refunds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/exchange-and-refund-azure-reservations#cancel-exchange-and-refund-policies) still is:

> We're currently not charging an early termination fee, but in the future there might be a 12% early termination fee for cancellations.

Best option though would be to run tests on your current setup, deploy a premium v3 for a few hours and do the same tests so you can check for your specific setup.

Comment: Awesome find on the 3 year discount - that makes them nearly the same.